# Access a variable outside of a function

Tags: php

I would elaborate further on this if I could, but the main problem I'm having is I can't access a variable outside of a function. I've tried both methods which I have below.

**Here is my source:**

```
function register($rand, $code) {
    global $rand, $access_token;
    if ($code == $access_token)
        $rand = rand('100000','1000000');
}   

echo $rand;
```

Comment: I cant see any where you called the function?

Comment: Should work ok, if you call the function. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gz9-x72

Comment: Using global I shouldn't have too..

Comment: @ChristianRankin Using global doesn't mean the function will run itself. It still needs to be called.

Comment: DarkCthulhu, worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function register($rand, $code) {
    if ($code == $access_token)
        $rand = rand('100000','1000000');
}
```

then call function first

```
register('1','2');
 echo $rand;
```

Comment: Sorry, but when calling register(1,2), what do those numbers represent? Can't I just put register($rand)

Comment: means you are passing the value of $rand and $code parameter from your function..

Comment: You're method was effective, but DarkCthulhu said it best above. 
register(0) worked.

Comment: @ChristianRankin don`t worry both are still the same they just differ in there parameters Darkchuchu only pass 1 parameters but here you passed 2 parameters .Because your function above state that you must pass 2 certain parameters..

Answer (score 1):

may be it's help for you

```
function register($rand, $code) {
    global $rand, $access_token;
    if ($code == $access_token) {
        $rand = rand('100000','1000000');
    }



return $rand;
}
```

echo register($rand, $code);

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using arguments instead of using $GLOBALS or using global $var, because its recommended [take a look at these questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions) & [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)]

```
function register($rand, $code, $access_token) {
    if ($code == $access_token){
      $rand = rand('100000','1000000');
    }
    return $rand;
}

echo register($rand, $code, $access_token);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should run ok, if you are calling function before accessing `$rand` variable.

```
function register($rand, $code) {
    global $rand, $access_token;
    if ($code == $access_token) {
        $rand = rand('100000','1000000');
    }
    echo "\nInside Function = ".$rand;
    echo $access_token;
}   

register(100, '');
echo "\nOutside Function = ".$rand;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function before $rand is set. Global $rand inside the function does not set any value before you call register().

```
<?php
    function register($rand, $code) {
        global $rand, $access_token;
        if ($code == $access_token)
            $rand = rand('100000','1000000');
    }   
    register('x', 'y');

    echo $rand;
?>
```

If PHP would set all global values before calling functions, then think of the following. What would $rand be set to? It only makes sense when one of the functions are called.

```
<?php
function a() {
global $rand = 1;
}
function b() {
global $rand = 2;
}
```